# Date format changes while using levels in R

Tags: r, tibble

I have an df in r which is like the following :

```
# A tibble: 70 x 2

value Month_considered
dbl> <S3: yearmon>   
24.8  Apr 2017        
47.0  Apr 2017        
35.2  Apr 2017        
19.4  Apr 2017        
30.9  Apr 2017        
6.64  Apr 2017        
10.7  Apr 2017        
11.5  May 2017        
36.3  May 2017        
6.74  May 2017        
# ... with 60 more rows
```

So when I do  `levels(intrc_flow$Month_considered)` or `unique(intrc_flow$Month_considered)` the output I get is as following:

```
 [1] Apr-17 May-17 Jun-17 Jul-17 Aug-17 Sep-17 Oct-17 Nov-17 Dec-17 Jan-18 Feb-18
12 Levels: Apr-17 Aug-17 Dec-17 Feb-18 Jan-18 Jul-17 Jun-17 Mar-17 ... Sep-17
```

How do I get the levels output as `Apr 2017` instead of `Apr-17`.Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `format(unique(intrc_flow$Month_considered), format="%b %Y")`?

Comment: `intrc_flow$Month_considered` is an `yearmon` object or a factor?

Comment: unique(as.yearmon(intrc_flow$Month_considered, "%b-%y"))unique(as.yearmon(intrc_flow$Month_considered, "%b-%y"))